# Getting Incorrect return in java accessing sql database

Tags: java, sql

This is the code im using in java to query the database

```
                connect = DriverManager.getConnection (url, "user", "pass");
                state = connect.createStatement();
                String meetID = "SELECT GamerTag FROM backup";
                ResultSet rs = state.executeQuery(meetID);

                   while(rs.next()){
                        System.out.println(rs.toString());
                   }
```

Im not getting the values of the row in the database im getting this instead

```
com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet@108137c9
```

Comment: Did you try rs.getString("GamerTag") ?

Comment: You might want to go through the JDBC tutorial before continuing: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're printing the result of the [`toString` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()) of the Recordset object, which appears to print out the object's name and hashcode.

Instead, try to print the value of a column.  Perhaps using `getString`:

```
System.out.println(rs.getString("GamerTag"));
```

The [documentation for Java's recordset](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) looks confusing, you might be better off searching for examples.

Comment: Thanks im adding it to an arrayList so do i add rs.getString("GamerTag") or  rs.toString()? Your way printed the right result

Comment: `rs.toString()` returns a string that contains the name of the recordset class and the hashtag of the object.  It's only useful for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

What do you expect rs.toString() should do it will just print the hash of the resultsetObject if you want to get the column values you should do this way

```
while(rs.next()){
System.out.println(rs.getString("yourFirstColumnName")+"  "+
                           rs.getString("yourSecondColumnName")+"  "+
                          rs.getString("yourThirdColumnName"));
}
```

*Really you should use PreparedStatement. In your case though you are not using any parameterizedQuery but One of the major benefits of using PreparedStatement is better performance. PreparedStatement gets pre compiled.*

*In database and there access plan is also cached in database, which allows database to execute parametric query written using prepared statement much faster than normal query because it has less work to do. You should always try to use PreparedStatement.*

So you can do something like this

```
String query = "SELECT GamerTag FROM backup"
PreparedStatement st =connect.prepareStatement("query");
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
```